# How i send value when i click button to server and popup directive

Tags: angularjs, get

> When i click the button i want to send the val of label `number` to
>   the func  getUserDetails in controller and loop the data that returnd
>   in result  on the directive and popup to the screen the directive

```
<div ng-controller="IndexController">
<label id="number" >5</label>
<input type="button" ng-click="getUserDetails()" >
</div>


app.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {   
    $scope.getUserDetails = function() {
        var result = $http.get("/getUserDetails?id=" + number)

    }   
}]);


directive 
<div ng-repeat m in result>
     <label>{{m.a}}</label>
      <label>{{m.b}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem? That's not how a ng-repeat should look either.

Comment: the problem is that i dnot know the syntax

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).  Your code has a few structural errors, and you seem to be referring to the `<label>` as if the value will change somehow (Probably through some JavaScript), and if that is the case, the script that is populating the value should already know what it is, to supply it to your function.  We aren't seeing enough of your situation to provide an accurate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="IndexController">
  <div ng-repeat="user in userList">
     <label id="{{user.number}}">{{user.number}}</label>
     <input type="button" ng-click="getUserDetails({{user.number}})">   
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
app.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {   
    $scope.getUserDetails = function(number) {
        var httpPromise = $http.get("/getUserDetails?id=" + number);
        httpPromise.then (function (result) {
            $scope.detailsList = result.data.detailsList;
        }).catch ( function (error) {
            //log error
        }); 
    }   
}]);
```